# Unknown key bridge netplan config for KVM

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Can not get my bridge to work for KVM, running Ubuntu. I started a VM to test but VM can not reach outside.

I get this error in debug:

```
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:20:3: Error in network definition: unknown key 'bridge'
  bridge:
  ^
```

And here is my netplan config file.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
      eno1:
          addresses: [10.0.0.110/24]
          gateway4: 10.0.0.1
          nameservers:
              addresses: [10.0.0.1, 1.1.1.1, 10.0.0.102]
          dhcp4: no
          dhcp6: no
      eno2:
          dhcp4: no
          dhcp6: no
  bridge:
      br0:
          interfaces: [eno2]
          addresses: [10.0.0.111/24]
          gateway4: 10.0.0.1
          nameservers:
              addresses: [10.0.0.1, 1.1.1.1, 10.0.0.102]
          dhcp4: no
          dhcp6: no
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your configuration.
Please correct the following line.

```
network:
  bridge: => bridges:
```